# Access output directory in prepublish script in ASP.NET5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, project.json

The `project.json` file can contain a `prepublish` entry to execute some scripts before publishing of a package. There are several variables available in those scripts, according to their [wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#scripts), for example `%project:Directory%`

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "dir %project:Directory%" ]
}
```

Is there any way to access the input and output directory used for publishing? I see in visual studio the actual paths:

```
Publishing files to E:\Projects\WebPlatform\artifacts\bin\DemoLauncher\Release\PublishOutput
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\DemoLauncher70\' -dest:contentPath='E:\Projects\WebPlatform\artifacts\bin\DemoLauncher\Release\PublishOutput'
```

However i cannot seem to get the values in "prepublish" script. I would like something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "dir %outputDirectory%" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn's out that `dnx/dnu` publish command doesn't support this, however the commands will be replaced with `dotnet publish` which will provide `publish:OutputPath` variable.

The ticket for [is available here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3374#issuecomment-191357516) and relevant code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-publish/PublishCommand.cs#L99-L104)